# Expressing a function as a power series

Tags: power-series, legendre-polynomials

How can I represent
$$(t^2+1)^{-1/2}$$
as a power series? What I know is 
$$\frac1{1-t} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$$ 
$$-1<t<1$$

Additional: I encountered this problem when solving Legendre polynomial relation

$$P_{2n}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{1\cdot3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}$$
using the generating function.

Comment: See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: add : t must be :   $0<=t<=1$

Comment: @Lucian it does not related to binomial

Comment: Consider the function $f(t)=(1-t)^{-1/2}$. It is not very hard to find the $n$-th derivative of $f(t)$, and therefore the Maclaurin series for $(1-t)^{-1/2}$. Then plug in $t=-x^2$.

Comment: i every situation you must determine the region of t, it is essential for convergence issues

Comment: Maybe one could notice that $\int (t^2+1)^{-1/2}\,dt=\sinh^{-1}t$. Then use the known Taylor expansion and take term-wise derivatives?

Comment: good point woolfitt